# python3 - child class does not inherit parent method when parent is in a separate file

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

In Python3.7.4 my child class is not inheriting a method from its parent when they are in separate files. Here are file snippets...

linkedlist.py

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data):       
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None

class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.header = None

    def print_list(self):       
        # print data in each node
```

lifo_queue.py

```
from linked_list import *

class Lifo(LinkedList):
  # definitions for pop() and push()
```

test.py

```
from lifo_queue import Lifo

myList = Lifo()
myList.push("abc")
myList.push("def")
myList.push("ghi")
myList.print_list()
```

running the program test.py returns an error, referring to the statement *myList.print_list()*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    myList.print_list()
AttributeError: 'Lifo' object has no attribute 'print_list'
```

I've seen similar patterns work in the past, but don't see what I'm doing wrong here. test.py runs okay if class definitions for Lifo and LinkedList are in the same file.

Comment: Can you post your full code for the classes please? And are all these files in the same directory?

Comment: Oops. In preparation to post the full code I realized linked_list.py didn't have the print_list definition. I had copied my files and was apparently editing and running  different files. A little embarrassing for my first stackoverflow post. Thanks for the feedback that helped me discover it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the name incorrect in the file where you are importing it.

In lifo_queue.py

```
from linked_list import *
```

But you have file name as

```
linkedlist.py
```